# How to wait for in process operations before canceling go routine

Tags: go, goroutine

I have a message consumer (eg: Kafka) that runs on a go routine with a for-select with a default case where it processes the received message:

```golang
type Consumer struct{}

func (c *Consumer) Start(ctx context.Context) {
    fmt.Println("Consumer is starting")
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("Consumer is stopping")
    }()

    i := 0
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("Context is done")
            return
        default:
            // msg, err := kafka.FetchMessage(ctx)
            fmt.Printf("[%d] Received message\n", i)
            <-time.After(3 * time.Second)
            fmt.Printf("[%d] Stopped processing\n", i)
            i++
        }
    }
}
```

In my main function, I have a channel that listen for cancelation signals. Whenever the cancel signal is received, I want to cancel the go routine by calling the context cancel function.

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Main Start")
    sigchan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigchan, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    consumer := &Consumer{}
    go func() {
        consumer.Start(ctx)
    }()

    <-sigchan
    fmt.Println("Received signal to shutdown")
    cancel()
}
```

The requisites of the system are:

- Message processing must be synchronous;
- Must not lose any in-progress operations (messages);

However, when I cancel the program by clicking CTRL + C, if a message is in processing the processing is not completed. How can I implement a feature that will cancel the consumer only after the last message is processed.

Go Playgroud: https://go.dev/play/p/kRUPPhwxwn7

Comment: Just cancel the context then wait for the goroutine to complete. You can't tell what the goroutine is doing, so it needs to return on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it exits immediately is because when `main()` returns, all goroutines abruptly stopped. There's nothing waiting until `consumer.Start` is finished.

Using [`signal.NotifyContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal#NotifyContext) is a bit more straight-forward, but we can accomplish it your way too.

```golang
// Your way, modified:
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Main Start")
    sigchan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigchan, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    go func() {
        <-sigchan
        fmt.Println("Received signal to shutdown")
        cancel()
    }()

    // Block until it exists, cancel in the background
    consumer := &Consumer{}
    consumer.Start(ctx)
}

// Allowing signal.NotifyContext to deal with it
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Main Start")
    ctx, cancel := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    defer cancel()

    consumer := &Consumer{}
    consumer.Start(ctx)
    fmt.Println("Shutting down")
}
```

Also, note that `CTRL+C` is not exactly equivalent to `kill -INT $PID`. The former will send `SIGINT` to every process in the foreground proc's `PGID`. This means forks may get killed before the main process can do it gracefully.